# i want to decrease count when already checked checkbox is unchecked. how do i do this?

Tags: android, xml, loops, checkbox, count

i was trying to make a list that will select only 3 symptoms.
for which i put a while loop that stops when count becomes 3.
count increases when a checkbox is checked but it doesn't decrease when it is unchecked again. How do i solve this. here is what i have done so far:-

**JAVA CODE**

```
public void onCheckboxClick (View view) {
        int count = 0;
        String a, b, c;
        CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        while(count<3){
            switch (view.getId()) {
                case R.id.checkBox1:
                     if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                           a = "Bad taste in mouth";
                        } else if (count == 1) {
                        b = "Bad taste in mouth";
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                        c = "Bad taste in mouth";
                     }
                     count++;
                     } else {

                     }
                     break;
                case R.id.checkBox2:
                     if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                           a = "Gap in between teeth";
                        } else if (count == 1) {
                           b = "Gap in between teeth";
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                           c = "Gap in between teeth";
                     }  
                     count++;
                     } else {

                     }
                     break;
                case R.id.checkBox3:
                     if (checkBox3.isChecked()) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                        a = "Bad breath";
                     } else if (count == 1) {
                        b = "Bad breath";
                     } else if (count == 2) {
                        c = "Bad breath";
                     }
                     count++;
                     } else {

                     }
                     break;
                case R.id.checkBox4:
                     if (checkBox4.isChecked()) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                           a = "Nasal pain";
                        } else if (count == 1) {
                           b = "Nasal pain";
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                           c = "Nasal pain";
                        }
                     count++;
                     } else {

                     }
                     break;
                case R.id.checkBox5:
                     if (checkBox5.isChecked()) {
                        if (count == 0) {
                           a = "Blurred vision";
                        } else if (count == 1) {
                           b = "Blurred vision";
                        } else if (count == 2) {
                           c = "Blurred vision";
                        }
                        count++;

                     } else {

                     }
                     break;
            }
        }
}
```

**XML CODE**

```
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bad taste in mouth"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClick"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Gap in between teeth"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClick"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Bad breath"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClick"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Nasal pain"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClick"/>
    <CheckBox
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Blurred vision"
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:onClick="onCheckboxClick"/>
```

Any help will be appreciated thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a while loop, use an OnCheckedChangeListener for each checkbox.

```
checkbox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked ) {
            count++;
        } else {
            count--;
        }

    if (count >= 3) {
    // do logic
    }

    }
});
```

etc...

Comment: but that doesn't limit the user from checking only 3 checkboxes. That is what i'm trying to do. plz hlp. thnx.